# Pdo execute is not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm trying a simple code before add with an encrypted password with password_hash().

**html**

```
<form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">                      
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Connection" /> 
</form>
```

**php**

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS membre_valide FROM membres WHERE password = :password AND email = :email');
$req->bindValue(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$data = $req->execute();
$req->closeCursor();

if ( $data['membre_valide'] != 0 ) {
    echo 'Connected';
}
else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

With one `echo` of `$data`, it always return `1`.
But when I run the SQL line in mysql, it return the good answer.

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `execute` the function but you don't `fetch` the results:

```
$exec = $req->execute();
    //$exec will be "true" if it executes; "false" if it doesn't

$data = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //fetch() for one row, fetchAll() to retrieve all rows
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request with execute() the return value is just an error code. So basically, this means the request was successfully done. To find the value, you want to fetch the value.
You should try `$count = (int) $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->membre_valide;`